# What's the equivalent of ifup under Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

What's the equivalent of [ifup](http://ss64.com/bash/ifup.html) under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's [The DevCon command-line utility functions as an alternative to Device Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272):

> The DevCon utility is a
>   command-line utility that acts as an
>   alternative to Device Manager. Using
>   DevCon, you can enable, disable,
>   restart, update, remove, and query
>   individual devices or groups of
>   devices. DevCon also provides
>   information that is relevant to the
>   driver developer and is not available
>   in Device Manager.

See [Using Devcon](http://robhaupt.blogspot.com/2008/07/using-devcon.html) for more info.

You may therefore use :

> devcon listclass Net

to figure out the name of the network adaptor in question, then just make a bat file with for example

> `devcon disable *ven_14E4*<br/>`
>   or
>  `devcon enable *ven_14E4*`

Comment: +1 That is a nice find.  And it does **way** more than toggling an interface. wow.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - it's an interactive program.  Type netsh.  At the prompt try:

```
> netsh interface ip set address 
        name="Local Area Connection" 
        source=static addr=192.168.0.10 
        mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.0.1 gwmetric=1
```

Answer (score 1):

> `ipconfig /renew` <adapter>